# htaccess rewrite subdomain to matching folder throws 400 error when containing underscore

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've tried using both of these methods:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(\w+)\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}:%1 !^/([^/]+)/([^:]*):\1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]
```

and

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Both work, except if the subdomain contains an _ it throws a 400 error.  How can I get these rewrite rules to work with subdomains that contain an underscore?

Example usage, going to:

sub_domain.example.com should show the contents of example.com/sub_domain/ but instead throws a 400 error.

Comment: A `400` means that the request was malformed. Rename your .htaccess to something else and then try `http://sub_domain.example.com/` in a browser to see what you get.

Comment: Ah good find, so would I check something in apache conf?

Comment: Hmm so never new this but it turns out _ in the subdomain is not valid.  It can be used in some DNS records like TXT and such but not to be used as an actual hostname. [link]https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname#Restrictions_on_valid_host_namess[/link]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an underscore in a hostname is not valid.

http://domainkeys.sourceforge.net/underscore.html